# Ruby Hash Of Array with Loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this Hash:

```
{:id => [RN1223,BN3233], :name => ['Red Ring','Blue Bangles'], :category => ['Ring','Bangles']}
```

And I would like to get a new Hash with the following format:

```
{:id => 'RN1223', :name => 'Red Ring', :category => 'Ring'},
{:id => 'BN3233', :name => 'Blue Bangles', :category => 'Bangles'}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have this this hash

{:id => [RN1223,BN3233], :name => ['Red Ring','Blue Bangles'], :category => ['Ring','Bangles']}

I want convert in to this form 

{:id => 'RN1223', :name => 'Red Ring', :category => 'Ring'},

{:id => 'BN3233', :name => 'Blue Bangles', :category => 'Bangles'}

Answer (score 1):

```
 hsh = {:id => ['RN1223','BN3233'],
        :name => ['Red Ring','Blue Bangles'],
        :category => ['Ring','Bangles']}
 hsh.values.transpose.map {|arr| Hash[[:id, :name, :category].zip arr]}
 # => [{:id=>"RN1223", :name=>"Red Ring", :category=>"Ring"},
 #     {:id=>"BN3233", :name=>"Blue Bangles", :category=>"Bangles"}]
```